# Filter foreign key choises in django models

Tags: django, django-models

Is there are possibility to filter ForeignKeys field query in djano models?
(by default django uses objects.all() i guess).

See the example bellow :

Server -> Conf -> sip_conf -> peer -> context

Server -> ext_conf -> context

The contextFK can be only in list of the context's_ID which contain in the ext_conf model for the same ServerFK for Conf and ext_conf;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's it's a relative straight-forward limitation, you can use [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Anything too complicated, you'll need to override the `ModelForm`:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['my_fk_field'].queryset = self.fields['my_fk_field'].queryset.filter(...)
```

Comment: Filtering in ModelForm will protect only in UI. But what about code?django Console? I guess nothing. This would help, but not completely;

Comment: Like I said, you have `limit_choices_to`, which will work everywhere. If you can use that, you're golden. If it's not robust enough for your use case, then all you have is the form, so yeah, direct creation through the shell will not respect it.

Comment: Thank's for answering, Chris. I will try to filter throught limit_choises_to, and will post the solution if it will be found.